# how to show google Ads Dynamically without adding adview in layout file

Tags: android

I have only view in android layout file but i want to show Add in my application , i search many things but do not get solution, please help how i insert Ads dynamically without layout file.

Comment: can you please write in elaborate manner.

Comment: in my xml file don't have any layout, in that i am using view, in that i cannot add textview edit text , nthing, now i want to show ad in my app, how?